# Encrypt/decrypt personal data

Tags: encryption

I have a scenario where I need to encrypt personal(not sensitive) data like name, phone number, address etc. The idea is to use AES with 128-bit key. Should I used the same key stored somewhere in the configuration files for encryption of all user's data ? Or we should generate a new key for each user and store it in the database corresponding to each user.

Comment: I would recommend one key. Safer then to save keys in database.

Comment: If you're storing the key and encrypted data in the database, what's to stop an attacker who has gained access to the database from using the key to decrypt the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same key for all users.

Also, do NOT store that key in database nor hardcoded in your program.

Finally, one thing you can do if you are using Windows is encrypting that key with [Data Protection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It solves the main question of "where should i store the key"... as long as physical access on the server is controlled.